# COUNTIFS when counting distinct values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a table that looks something like this

[image]

what I want to do is have a formula that counts how many distinct machines are used on each hospital in between 04/06/2021 and 07/06/2021

So I would get something like this

[image]

I feel like this could be done with a COUNTIFS but somehow make it count only distinct values. I'm just not sure of how I could do this. Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried with countifs(), the help shows examples.

Comment: A pivot table will give it to you.

Comment: If you have office 365 you can use the `UNIQUE` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the comments, if you have the newest version of Excel you can use functions like `FILTER`, `COUNTA`, and `UNIQUE`.

For example, after getting the unique hospitals with `UNIQUE`, try something like:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(
FILTER($B$2:$B$10,
(($C$2:$C$10<DATEVALUE("1/5/2021"))*
($C$2:$C$10>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2021"))*
($A$2:$A$10=$F2)))))
```

[image]